# A list initialised in C# has elements in it already

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity, whilst using C#, I initialised a list:

```
public List<int> sequence = new List<int>();
```

However, I noticed that when using the list later, it had more elements than I expected. I ran this code to debug it:

```
void Start () {
        Debug.Log(sequence.Count);
        sequence.Clear ();
        Debug.Log(sequence.Count);
        sequence.Add (0);
        sequence.Add (1);
        sequence.Add (2);
        sequence.Add (3);
        Debug.Log(sequence.Count);
}
```

This gave the output of:

```
4
0
4
```

I would have expected the output to be `0 0 4`, since the list should be created with 0 elements in it.

For some reason that I haven't been able to work out, the list is being created with 4 elements in it.

Firstly, can anyone reproduce this at all? And secondly, can anyone work out why this is happening (it's easily fixable enough with `sequence.Clear()`)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ahem you are adding 4 elements after clearing the list. What else do you expect to get from Count after this action?

Comment: Sorry, should have made it clearer. I expect the output to be `0 0 4`, since the list should be created with 0 elements in it.

Comment: @RenéVogt No, since in Unity global variables for a class (that can be accessed by other methods of that class) must be declared outside the scope of any of those methods. So, the declaration happens before and outside the Start method.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. Are the initialization and that method the only accesses to `sequence`?

Comment: I'm guessing that you've set 4 values in the inspector view and that's why it starts up with 4

Comment: @m.rogalski Yes! Just realised that for some reason, in the inspector view, it had the length set to 4. I don't remember doing that, so I'm not sure how that happened. Could you post that as an answer so that I can close the question, please?

Comment: You can just delete it.

Comment: You can just close this question. It wont have much impact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that for whatever reason, the list had the number of elements set to 4 in the inspector. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In Unity3D, a public field which is serializable is the same as putting the `[SerializeField]` attribute before the field's declaration. If this field is part of another serializable class (usually a `MonoBehaviour`), Unity will store the values in the object. The values are saved by the editor (when the game isn't running), stored on disk, and loaded again whenever you open the project. When you instantiate your object in the scene, that object will also have a copy of the public/serialized variable.

So to check if you've specified values for this object, find the `MonoBehaviour` it belongs to in the editor. Don't look for the script. Look for the `GameObject`. Scroll down to where `sequence` is shown in the inspector. Are there values specified? If so, those values will always be present after the object containing the script (the component) is instantiated.